# How To Insert PK (Primary Key) in Table1 To FK(Foreign Key) in Table2 then show it the result

Tags: php, mysql, insert, foreign-keys, primary-key

I have problems with mysql and PHP.
First of all
I have 2 tables:

table_customer

- id_cust --> auto_increment, not null and PK
- cust_name
- address
- sex

table_list

- id_list --> auto_increment,not null and PK
- id --> FK from table_customer
- list_name
- detail

I want to ask how to insert data to those tables, table customer must be filled but table_list was optional, 
then how to show it with PHP because I've tried it  failed. I hope someone could help me.

My php code is like this:

```
<?php

$insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO id_cust (cust_name, address, sex)
VALUES ('$name', '$address', 'sex')");

?>
```

I didn't understand where I should put the `SELECT` command for inserting into FK tables.

Comment: And what did you try, where you failed?

Comment: Were you getting an error? Are you asking how to get the insert id from `table_customer`?

Comment: please show us what you've already tried, so that we can give some advises

Comment: @Jason McCreary-->i didn't see an error but the data can't be inserted in tables from php form

Answer (score 0):

Queries you should execute in order:

```
//to begin transaction (lock the table)
BEGIN

//insert your customer
INSERT INTO table_customer (cust_name, address, sex) VALUES ( '$name' , '$address', '$sex')

//select last auto generated ID from customer table
SELECT id FROM table_customer ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1

//fetch the id selected in last query to $cID and use it in this query
INSERT INTO table_list (id, list_name, detail) VALUES ( $cID, '$listName', '$detail' )

//commit changes and end transaction
COMMIT
```

Remember this is only example, and I didn't write any php code (I accume you can do it yourself). To get it to work you will have to change bits and pieces. but the key is to LOCK and UNLOCK the table (use transaction) so no other row can be added to customers before you actually get the latest id...

Comment: sorry i'm not read it for a few days, i'm still not understand,can you explain it more details,,